# How To Only Read One Part Of A Line In Python

Tags: python

I am working on making a program that will read a txt file that is full of binary, then turn the binary into ASCII, and print the outcome. I need to read only parts of the lines, so say I had 00100001 and 00100110 on the same line, how do I make my program only read 0010000, and ignore 00100110?

Comment: This is going to depend on exactly how the lines are laid out - are there any separation characters, for example? Are the columns fixed-width? **What have you tried**, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: There are no seperation characters. I tried using `f.readlines(char)` and `f.readline(char)`. Both returned error. The problem is that I cannot secifiy which binary number to read. It reads both of the binary numbers, and it just makes a mess of 0's and 1's.

Comment: If it's always e.g. 8 bits, then use slices: `line[:8]`, `line[8:16]`, etc.

Comment: text file full of binary???  I assume you mean instead a binary file that has some text.  Have you tried the *struct* module?  And, yeah, post your code, don't English-explain it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read()` takes optional argument which is a size of string to read. So you may use it as follows:

```
with open('numbers.txt') as f:
    f.read(8)  # read up to 8 chars from first line
    f.readline()  # skip to next line
```

Certainly not a full answer (both problem definition and input file format are not precised), but it may be a good place to start.

Still, personally I'd read file line by line and simply perform some unified operation on each line.